# Generic way to timeout async operations in boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

`boost::asio` provides many async actions i.e. `ip::tcp::resolver.async_resolve`, `ip::tcp::socket.async_{connect, read, write}`.

The current way to timeout these operations is to add a [wrapper class with a deadline timer attached](http://sourceforge.net/p/asio/mailman/message/24041372/).

Is there a generic way to add timeouts to all these operations - i.e. a templated method/class or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer::expires_at](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_deadline_timer/expires_at/overload3.html) is for that, and the examples:
[A collection of examples showing how to cancel long running asynchronous operations after a period of time.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples/cpp03_examples.html#boost_asio.examples.cpp03_examples.timeouts)